# Continuously update state variable price from API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two state variables

```
const [cartList, setCartList] = useState([]);
const [tabledata, setTabledata] = useState(localStorage.getItem("items"))
```

`tableData` is initiated from local storage

`cartList` will be an array of objects with complete list and an example will be like

```
[
   {id: 1, name: pen, sku: 1001, price: 5},
   {id: 2, name: a4-book, sku: 1005, price: 2},
   {id: 3, name: usb-16gb, sku: 1010, price: 15},
   {id: 4, name: usb-32gb, sku: 1021, price: 28}
]
```

`tableData` is also an object array and will have some items and an example will be like

```
[
   {id: 2, name: a4-book, sku: 1005, price: 1.5},
   {id: 4, name: usb-32gb, sku: 1021, price: 22}
]
```

`cartList` has my latest price for each item, i want to update the `tabledata` to get the price for corresponding items (by id) from `cartList` every 5 minutes.

what is the best way to achieve this continuously ? so the `tabledata` element price is up to date with `cartList` price for corresponding items?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch `cartList` and update `tableData` and `localStorage` right away. However for doing this every 5 minutes, simply wrap the fetch call in a `setInterval()` call.

```js
const FIVE_MINUTES_MS = 5 * 60 * 1000;
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => fetch("/api/cartlist")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(list => {
      setCartList(list);
      const tableDataNew = tableData.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        price: list.find(cartItem => cartItem.name === item.name).price
      }));
      setTableData(tableDataNew);
      localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(tableDataNew));
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err)), FIVE_MINUTES_MS);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

The important bit to understand here is that I copy the updated prices from `cartList` after it is fetched and then update `tableData` while also storing it in `localStorage`.

The return statement is to stop this process e.g. when the component unmounts.

I haven't tested this but I hope this gives an idea of the flow.

Comment: Thanks mate. I got an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price') - but the element is named price in both the object lists

Comment: This could be because it didn't find the `tableData` item in `cartList`, please check if the `cartList` is populated and contains i.e. is superset of all `tableData` items

Comment: BTW you have to `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"))` in the `useState()` call in your question.

Comment: I checked again, the reason it is giving me the undefined error is because, setCartList(list); is not setting the cartList. I did a console.log below the set line and it shows an empty array []. so the following map line is giving a type error

Comment: Oh my bad, I can directly use `list` instead of `cartList`. I have updated the code, plz try again.

Comment: Excellent, that was it. It is working now. However i find the setinterval timing is a bit inconsistent. I will try to play with it. appreciate your help.

Comment: Found an issue. Every time the setinterval reruns the code, the tabledata is deleted except for first item in the list. If i have 6, after the next run, it goes back to just 1. Not sure why?